# How to Add more than one products of same id with different sizes in laravel moltin cart?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, moltin

I am trying to add more than one product having same ID but different sizes with Moltin cart. Problem here is, if I am trying to add the same product with different sizes into the Cart, it just increments the quantity instead of appending it. I googled for a solution but I found this happens because of passing the same ID into the `Cart::insert()` method.

Cart insert Method is:

```
Cart::insert(array(
    'id' => $product->id,
    'name' => $product->title,
    'price' => $product->price,
    'dimension'=>null,
    'unit'=>$product->unit,
    'quantity' => $quantity,
    'image' => $product->image,
    'tax' =>$product->taxvalue,
    'taxtype'=>$product->tax,
    'pincode' =>$pincode,
    'shippingfee'=>Session::get('shippingfee'),
    'retailerId' =>$retailerIdfromProductId
));
```

I want to append a new product if the dimension is not null. How do I do this?

Comment: You should really be having different `ids` for different products with different sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used the [Moltin](https://github.com/moltin/cart) cart package, but looking at the [code](https://github.com/moltin/cart/blob/master/src/Moltin/Cart/Cart.php) it looks like it builds the item identifier using a combination of the `id` field and an `options` array field. Therefore, if the `id` is the same, but the `options` are different, it should insert two different items in your cart.

Can you do something like this:

```
// first item with no dimension
Cart::insert(array(
    'id' => $product->id,
    'name' => $product->title,
    'price' => $product->price,
    'unit' => $product->unit,
    'quantity' => $quantity,
    'image' => $product->image,
    'tax' => $product->taxvalue,
    'taxtype' => $product->tax,
    'pincode' => $pincode,
    'shippingfee' => Session::get('shippingfee'),
    'retailerId' => $retailerIdfromProductId,
    'options' => array(
        'dimension' => null
    )
));

// second item with 'M' dimension
Cart::insert(array(
    'id' => $product->id,
    'name' => $product->title,
    'price' => $product->price,
    'unit' => $product->unit,
    'quantity' => $quantity,
    'image' => $product->image,
    'tax' => $product->taxvalue,
    'taxtype' => $product->tax,
    'pincode' => $pincode,
    'shippingfee' => Session::get('shippingfee'),
    'retailerId' => $retailerIdfromProductId,
    'options' => array(
        'dimension' => 'M'
    )
));
```